# Is it possible to generate a pool of lightning transaction invoices in advance?

Tags: lightning-network, invoices, merchant-services

When dealing with normal on-chain transactions, we can generate a large number of bitcoin addresses that can then be stored separately and used to receive payments at a later date.

I am aware that a lightning node must be reachable when a sender wants send a payment. I am also aware that reusing a lightning transaction compromises both older and newer transactions.

That said, I would still like to know if it is technically possible to generate a large pool of lightning invoices (to store on a server) in the same way normal bitcoin addresses can be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; unlike a Bitcoin address, Lightning invoices have a built-in timestamp and an expiration time. They also have information, such as the amount of Bitcoin (and sometimes routing information), that changes in an unpredictable fashion.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I found the following link which provides more information about how lightning invoices are generated: https://docs.lightning.engineering/the-lightning-network/lightning-overview/understanding-lightning-invoices and https://github.com/lightning/bolts/blob/master/11-payment-encoding.md